# slickgrid onAddNewRow

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am able to insert data to database using slickgrid, but it only can be done at the last row.

Is it possible to add the row at any line?

For example: 
I want to put the empty line at row 3 by using

```
grid.getData().splice(varCurrentRowNumber - 1, 0, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but you should use [dataView](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#updating-data) it makes these things WAY easier.

```
dataView.insertItem(varCurrentRowNumber - 1, {'id': 'gotta put something here'});
```